# Aws cloudformation: How to prevent Aurora RDS from replacement during Engine Version upgrade?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

We are using Aurora RDS that's provisioned and configured via Cloudformation. This is the relevant snippet from the template:

```
Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
Properties: 
  DeletionProtection: true
  Engine: aurora
  EngineVersion: 5.6.1
```

Now we want to upgrade the engine version to say 5.6.2. The  [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbcluster.html) says that Update on EngineVersion requires a replacement which means wiping out all data. Is there a way to safely update the version?

Answer (score 0):

Use `aws rds modify-db-cluster` API in this case instead of depending on Cloudformation's "stack modification". Resource modification's that are marked as "requires Replacement" depends on the service to handle the replacement. It might be worth trying that on a test cluster - just to see how Aurora's cloudformation support handles it. But if this is a one time fix up, then I highly recommend against it. Just use the CLI, fix your cluster, and then fix your CFN templates. Hope this helps!